# PHP function isPrime() not working

Tags: php

please help me with code to check if numbers in a table is prime: this is my code below. I used the isPrime function but I get an error where by when I call the function in the table it returns the words "isPime"

```
<?php 
      $x="num1"; 
      $y="num2"; 

      if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 

          $start=$_POST['num1']; 
          $end=$_POST['num2']; 

          echo "<table width='250' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='4' border='1'>"; 
          echo "<tr><td>Number</td><td>Odd or Even?</td><td>Prime?</td></tr>"; 

          for ($start;$start<=$end;$start++) { 

              $answer=$start;  
              $number=$answer; 
              $check="text"; 
              $num=$answer; 

                  if($number%2==0) { 

                      $check="Even"; 

                  } else { 

                      $check="Odd"; 

                  } 

                { } 

           echo "<tr><td>$answer</td><td>$check</td><td>

    <?php ?>

    </td></tr>"; 

        }  echo "</table>"; 

   } ?>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: When you are writing a question there is preview area at the bottom of the page.

Comment: <?php
$x="num1";
$y="num2";
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$start=$_POST['num1'];
$end=$_POST['num2'];
echo "<table width='250' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='4' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Number</td><td>Odd or Even?</td><td>Prime?</td></tr>";
for ($start;$start<=$end;$start++)
{
$answer=$start;
$number=$answer;
$check="text";
$num=$answer;
if($number%2==0)
{
$check="Even";
}
else
{
$check="Odd";
}
{
}

echo "<tr><td>$answer</td><td>$check</td><td><?php ?></td></tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
}
?>

Comment: In order to get an answer you need to post both the exact code and the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: I post your code from comment to your question... if you see (or no) you have some error to close `{ }` the right way and php tags

Comment: PHP doesn't have an isPrime() function, you'll have to write one.

Comment: ...and the function `isPrime()` is where?

Comment: sorry to all, I am new on this site. hence the mistakes. aldanux, it was giving me error so I removed it from my code.  this is what I wrote function isPrime($answer){
If($answer==1)
return false;

If($answer==2)
return true;

If($answer%2==0) {
return false;
}

for($i=3; $i<=ceil(sqrt($answer));$i=$i+2)
{
If($answer%Si==0)
return false;
}
return true;
}

Comment: You removed the part of the code that was giving you an error that you're asking about from your code? I hope you see the problem with that. Please [edit] your question (code doesn't really have a place in [so] comments) and add the code back so it gives the mentioned error, and make sure to test it again before doing so - it's often a source of endless frustration to try to figure out what's wrong with an original code sample if only given an incorrectly reconstructed one that doesn't give the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the entire prime check and you aren't even printing anything in your third column.

Also someone seems to have deleted your code in the first EDIT and changed it in the second. I somehow had a copy of the first edit and could make an example.

This is a working example within your code:

```
<?php 

$x="num1"; $y="num2"; 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{ 
    $start=$_POST['num1']; $end=$_POST['num2']; 
    echo "<table width='250' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='4' border='1'>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>Number</td><td>Odd or Even?</td><td>Prime?</td></tr>"; 
    for ($start;$start<=$end;$start++) 
    { 
        $answer=$start; $number=$answer; $check="text"; $num=$answer; 
        if($number%2==0) 
            { $check="Even"; } 
        else 
            { $check="Odd"; } 
        $prime = (isPrime($number)? 'Yes':'No');
        echo "<tr><td>$answer</td><td>$check</td><td>$prime</td></tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</table>"; 
} 
function isPrime($num) {
    //1 is not prime. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one
    if($num == 1)
        return false;

    //2 is prime (the only even number that is prime)
    if($num == 2)
        return true;

    /**
     * if the number is divisible by two, then it's not prime and it's no longer
     * needed to check other even numbers
     */
    if($num % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks the odd numbers. If any of them is a factor, then it returns false.
     * The sqrt can be an aproximation, hence just for the sake of
     * security, one rounds it to the next highest integer value.
     */
    for($i = 3; $i <= ceil(sqrt($num)); $i = $i + 2) {
        if($num % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: This prime calculation is not correct... Instead of `$num == 1` and `$num == 2` just use `$num < 2` because you have no check on negative numbers.

Comment: This Prime calculation is correct. I cannot change `$num == 1` and `$num == 2` to `$num < 2`  because there are two different results.  1 isn't a prime and 2 is. Also negative numbers are by default not a prime. If you would accept negative numbers you would need to return false for negative integers and non-integers `if($num < 0 || !is_int($num) ) return false;`. But mostly you would only use this function if you expect positive integers. And I can assume OP's `$num` are always positive integers, because of his wanted output.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php 
  $x="num1"; 
  $y="num2"; 

  if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 

      $start=$_POST['num1']; 
      $end=$_POST['num2']; 

      echo "<table width='250' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='4' border='1'>"; 
        echo "<tr><td>Number</td><td>Odd or Even?</td><td>Prime?</td></tr>"; 

      for ($start;$start<=$end;$start++) { 

          $answer=$start;  
          $number=$answer; 
          $check="text"; 
          $num=$answer; 

          if($number%2==0) 
          { 
              $check="Even"; 
          } 
          else 
          { 
              $check="Odd"; 
          } 

        if(isPrimeNumber($number))
        {   
            $pirme_status = "Yes";  
        }
        else
        {
            $pirme_status = "No";   
        }   

       echo "<tr><td>$answer</td><td>$check</td><td>$pirme_status</td><</tr>";



    }  echo "</table>"; 

}
```

and PHP function is

```
function isPrimeNumber($number)
{
    $flag = true;
    $max_count = ceil($number/2);
    for($i=2; $i<$max_count; $i++)
    {
        if($number%$i==0)
        {
            $flag = false;
                    break;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
?>
```